# Break and Continue (C)

Tags: c, break

> "Simon Says" is a memory game where "Simon" outputs a sequence of 10 characters (R, G, B, Y) and the user must repeat the sequence. Create a for loop that compares the two strings starting from index 0. For each match, add one point to userScore. Upon a mismatch, exit the loop using a break statement.
>
> Ex: The following patterns yield a userScore of 4:
>
> simonPattern: R, R, G, B, R, Y, Y, B, G, Y
>
> userPattern:  R, R, G, B, B, R, Y, B, G, Y

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char simonPattern[50] = "";
   char userPattern[50] = "";
   int userScore = 0;
   int i = 0;

   userScore = 0;
   strcpy(simonPattern, "RRGBRYYBGY");
   strcpy(userPattern, "RRGBBRYBGY");

   while (userPattern[i] = simonPattern[i]) {
      userScore = userScore + 1;
      ++i;
      if (userPattern[i] != simonPattern[i]) {
         break;
      }
   }

   printf("userScore: %d\n", userScore);

   return 0;
}
```

I tried running the code, but I got this

https://i.stack.imgur.com/QPfwB.png

Does anyone know what's causing the extra 1?

Thanks.

Comment: `while (userPattern[i] = simonPattern[i]) {` replace `=` with `==`. `      if (userPattern[i] != simonPattern[i]) {` is not necessary

Comment: Have you tried stepping through the code with a debugger or adding some `printf` statements to see what is happening in the main loop?

Comment: [Questions asking for homework help must include a summary of the work you've done so far to solve the problem, and a description of the difficulty you are having solving it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: Where did the output in that image come from?

Comment: Please show all required information here. Do not just add external links and no images/screenshots.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the condition in your while loop to use `==` not `=`. Right now you are making an assignment and not comparing the two meaning the first chars will always be the same and give a score of 1. You can then remove the if statement from inside the loop.

The assignment asks you to use a for loop and not a while. If you just move I into the for loop and fill out the rest, along with moving the increment to after the != check it would work.

Answer (score 1):

After seeing a bunch of answers, ran into the same problem in my WGU ZyBooks course and it is very similar to Potato's answer, just I was getting an error using his code due to the userPattern being of type String and the i being of type int not working. Added in the .charAt(i) after the strings and fixed the problem.

```
for (i = 0; userPattern.charAt(i) == simonPattern.charAt(i); ++i) {
    userScore = userScore +1;
    if (userPattern.charAt(i) != simonPattern.charAt(i)){
    break;
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while (simonPattern.at(i) == userPattern.at(i))
{
++i;
++userScore;
}
```

Comment: Pls just don;t paste your code here - consider providing some explaination

Answer (score 0):

Be sure to use a "FOR" loop, I see that you're using a "WHILE" loop. You will want to use the == comparative operator as opposed to the = assignment operator.

Here's my code and it worked out fine:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void) {
   char simonPattern[50];
   char userPattern[50];
   int userScore;
   int i;

   userScore = 0;
   strcpy(simonPattern, "RRGBRYYBGY");
   strcpy(userPattern, "RRGBBRYBGY");

   i = 0;

   for ( i = 0; userPattern[i] == simonPattern[i]; ++i) {
      userScore = userScore +1;
      if (userPattern[i] != simonPattern[i]){
         break;
      }
   }


   printf("userScore: %d\n", userScore);

   return 0;
}
```

Comment: The problem with this one is that because userPattern[i] == simonPattern[i]; is its own while statement, the negative comparison never hits, and break does not occur. Though it does work and satisfies the requirements (including break); it is more complex than what is being taught. The original post is correct minus the == instead of = like mentioned by @Neil Locketz. I have also posted an answer using a for statement that works and is along the lines of current learning being taught in the lab section.

Answer (score 0):

Using Java (what my lab was asking for):

```
// Assuming both patterns are the same length. 
// The particular question originally posted specifies 10. 
// Other questions specify assume same length.

for (i = 0; i < simonPattern.length(); ++i){
    if (simonPattern.charAt(i) == userPattern.charAt(i)){
        userScore++; // Can also use userScore = userScore + 1
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```

Using C#:

```
for (i = 0; i < simonPattern.Length; ++i) {
    if (simonPattern.ElementAt(i) == userPattern.ElementAt(i)) {
        userScore++;
    }
    else {
        break;
    }
}
```